# ¿Cómo puedo crear un efecto de desvanecimiento suave al hacer clic en un botón en HTML utilizando solo CSS y JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría que el contenido de un elemento se desvanezca gradualmente cuando se hace clic en un botón y que el contenido se vuelva visible nuevamente al hacer clic en el botón nuevamente. ¿Pueden proporcionar un ejemplo de código para lograr este efecto?"

Comment: En Google hay muchos ejemplo de códigos

Comment: Siempre muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. [es.so] no es un servicio del tipo _gimme the codez_ (que traducido sería como _dameh el códigoh_). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que presiones el botón al elemento le agregas una clase css, para eso puedes usar la función [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle), la cual agrega la clase si es que el elemento no cuenta con ella, y en caso contrario la remueve.

Hay varias formas de lograr este efecto, la más fácil es usando [Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Esta propiedad te permite establecer una transición cuando el valor de otra propiedad cambia (en tu caso `opacity`). Puedes establecer el tiempo que dura la transición y una [transition-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) que es una curva que permite variar la aceleración de la transición, por ejemplo puedes hacer que comience lento y termine de golpe

```js
function animar(){
 elemento.classList.toggle("oculto");
}
```

```css
#elemento{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  
  transition: opacity 0.9s ease-in;
}

.oculto{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="animar()">Animar</button>
<div id="elemento"></div>
```